# Converting 8086 assembler (MOV instruction) into machine code

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, mov

I need to translate the Assembler command `MOV AX,[0200]` into machine code of intels 8086 processor.
I already translated `MOV AL,[ALPHA]` in another task I've got. Here I found the `MOV AL/AX,addr` in the instruction set table, so I could translate the whole thing into `1010|0000 1010|0000` or `A0 10` in machine code.

I tend to use `MOV r/m1,r/m2` of the instruction set table, but I am not 100% sure because I got problems when selecting the `r/m` part. Since this is the preparation for an exam, I would be really happy if someone could help :)

Comment: Does the exam actually expect you to have all the opcode tables ***memorized***? That's craziness. You convert assembly language instructions into machine code using an assembler, not by hand!

Comment: we dont have to memorized tables...they giving us the lists ...but i dont understand have to make mod R/M